# How to present a keynote and start playing itunes music

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, itunes, keynote

When I am in that full-screen mode presenting a keynote, using the iTunes media keys seems to just exit the keynote instead of playing a song from iTunes.

How can I play a song from iTunes whilst staying inside the keynote presenter?

Comment: You can add the music you want to play to the slide

Comment: @Peter it needs to go across slides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Automator, AppleScript and a Keyboard Shortcut it is possible.

1. Open Automator
2. Create a new Service action
3. Make sure it receives 'no input' at all programs.
4. Drop a 'Run AppleScript' action in
5. Add this code:

`tell application "iTunes"
   play track "name-of-song-you-want-to-play"
end tell`

6. Save Automator Service Action
7. Open System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Services
8. At the bottom under 'General' you will find the action you just created
9. Select that item
10. Push the 'Add Shortcut' button
11. Press the shortcut you want to use, for example Alt + CMD X

When you are in fullscreen mode and arrive at slide 3. Just press the shortcut you chose. And voila the music will start.

Comment: "add this code" - inside the template of do I make the whole file that code?

Comment: Inside the Run AppleScript part inside Automator. No separate file needed.

Answer (score 1):

Keynote can play audio across all slides, but it needs to be inserted differently. Rather than using the Media button to insert audio you need to insert your audio via the Document icon and then click the Audio tab, and drop your audio tracking this way.

This audio then becomes a "Soundtrack" and will play across all slides in the presentation.

[image: Keynote, document settings]

Comment: I don't want audio across all slides, just from the third slide onwards.

Comment: Okay could you update your question with this new information?

Comment: could you please answer the question I asked? I never even asked about putting music into Keynote.

Comment: I think you can do it with AppleScript...